# Pandas Rolling Conditional Function

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

I'm having some trouble to use `.apply` or `.aggregate` in pandas on a rolling basis (assuming of course that it is the right way to solve my problem). Let's assume I have a dataframe with two columns A and B. I would like to create a column C that will contain the rolling mean of B if A is having the value of 1. And more generally I would like to be able to apply a custom function on a rolling basis with some conditions involving several columns of the dataframe (e.g. rolling sum of column A when B > x and/or C = y etc.).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1],'B': [50,40,50,-20,20,10,10,-5,-2]}, index = np.arange(9))
```

Desired output would be (assuming a rolling window of 3):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1],'B': [50,40,50,-20,20,10,10,-5,-2],\
 'C': [np.nan, np.nan, 46.67, 45, 50, np.nan, 10, 2.50, 1]}, index = np.arange(9))
```

I have tried to define a function `mean_1` as follows:

```
def mean_1(x):
    return np.where(x['A'] == 1, np.mean(x['B']), np.nan)

df2['C'] = df2.rolling(3).apply(mean_1)
```

and got the error: `'Series' object has no attribute 'A'`
I guess it is due related to the `raw = False` in the documentation
Thanks

Comment: What version of numpy and pandas are you using? I was not able to recreate your error.

Comment: @NabilDaoud pandas 1.1.2 and numpy 1.18.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize your solution:

```py
df2['C'] = df2['A'].eq(1).mul(df2['B']).rolling(3).sum()\
    .div(df2['A'].eq(1).rolling(3).sum())\
    .round(2)
```

If you are asking more general in terms of *any* function - my advise would be - always try to vectorize, generally avoid `.apply(...)`

Comment: Thanks! I never thought about breaking down everything using .eq, .mul, .div etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get close to what you're desired output.

`df2['C'] = df2.apply(lambda row: np.where(row['A']==1, row['B'], np.nan), axis=1).rolling(3, min_periods=1).apply(np.nanmean)`

The difference is that the above give a value for index 0 and 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is an interesting solution and having a value for index 0 and 1... I can live with that for now

Comment: @CTRX - check 2 other solution. Don't know about the size of the data - but I would speculate, that this approach will be significantly slower than others - single `.apply(...)` is already slow, in here you have 2 of them, some reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/11610186

Answer (score 1):

You can first mask the 'B' values where 'A' is not 1, then apply the rolling method:

```py
mask_map = df2.A != 1
df2['C'] = df2.B.mask(mask_map).rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean().round(2)
```

Output:

```
   A   B      C
0  1  50  50.00
1  1  40  45.00
2  1  50  46.67
3  0 -20  45.00
4  0  20  50.00
5  0  10    NaN
6  1  10  10.00
7  1  -5   2.50
8  1  -2   1.00
```

Note that the first values are not `NaN` because we specified `min_periods=1`. It means that we're taking the mean regardless the quantity of missing values. So, if that's the case, and if you really want to set the first values as `NaN`, this can be done with:

```
df2.iloc[:n-1, df2.columns.get_loc('C')] = np.nan
```

where `n` is the window size (3 in this case). This will return the exact desired output.

Best!

Comment: Just a note - I would generally trust that OP didn't mean to use `min_periods=1`, as it changes the result in a meaningful way here (your output differs from what OP requested). You can post it as a remark, after the answer matching the requirement, but don't base your answer on sheer speculation (a long shot - I would say - in this case)

Comment: I've mistakenly masked the output as well. Updated answer, thx! In fact, I assumed that the OP requires `min_periods=1` because the result for index 6 is 10, and there's only NaN other than the it's own value. But what do you mean by the OP doesn't want `min_periods=1`? Your answer does that (great answer, btw), but manually, since you're taking the mean regardless `NaN`.